# Use paste0() in subset()

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with different diagnosis codes and date of diagnosis. The dataframe looks as follows:

```
   id Diag1 Diag2.. Diag10 Date1 Date2.. Date10
   123 E052 F420.. F130 2015-9-20 2012-12-3.. 2007-2-5
   119 A041 D072.. E059 2008-1-15 2017-9-1.. 2014-6-8
   ...
```

I manage to select a list of codes and their corresponding dates. For 1 column the following code worked fine

```
code_list = c("E059","E052)
temp1 = subset(df, Diag1 %in% code_list, select = c(id, Diag1, Date1))
```

Since I have multiple columns for diagnosis and dates named Diag1,2,... and Date1,2..., I tried to use a for loop and `paste0` to name the variables.

```
for (i in 1:10){
    temp = subset(df, paste0("Diag",i) %in% code_list, select = c("id", paste0("Diag",i), paste0("Date",i)
}
```

But that doesn't work even when I set i=1 manually.

I have also looked up `assign()` function, but that doesn't seem to be useful in my case either. I was also wondering if this problem has something to do with the quotes produced by `paste0` function.

I was expecting a for loop resulting in 10 temp dataframes, then I can merge them together.
Any advice will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Lloyd_LiuSiyi It might help to clarify what your original data.frame looks like. Can you edit your question and share example data with `dput` and include a few rows of data? And also include what your final/desired end result should look like?

Comment: @Ben Thanks for your advice! I have edited the question so the df looks more clear.

Comment: There are two issues: (1) `subset` really isn't built for this kind of tasks. As per its documentation it is explicitly designed for *exploratory*, *interactive* use, not for programming. You *can* hack around this limitation (I do, in a package) but you probably shouldn't. Use conventional subsetting instead. (2) Your data is in wide format; solving your problem will become drastically easier once you pivot your data into long format (i.e. having 3 instead 21 columns). The easiest way to do this is to use ‘tidyr‘ in combination with ‘dplyr’.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks for pointing out my problem. Actually my data has a few hundred thousand patients and the number of diagnoses and dates is also large. So I'm a bit confused if issue 2 can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more convenient way but using `eval(parse(text=...))` will convert the characters into an expression, i.e. your variable :

```
temp = subset(df, eval(parse(text=paste0("Diag",i))) %in% code_list,
              select = c("id", paste0("Diag",i), paste0("Date",i)))
```

Comment: Hi Basti! I have not used it in the for loop yet but it worked when I specified i =1. Could you please explain a bit more how `eval(parse(text=...))` works?